# get a error while insert into json column while the document contains a json_string as value in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, json, insert

always get a error when insert into json column when the json document contains a json string as value

> msyql 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

sql with error:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(null, '{"a":"avalues","b":"{\"a\":\"avalues\"}"}');
```

but the sql below run well

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(null, '{"a":"avalues","b":"{\'a\':\'avalues\'}"}');
```

Comment: Please edit the question—you forgot to include the error message.

Comment: What kind of column type do you use (char/varchar/text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a literal backslash in a string, you need to use `\\`.

I got this to work on 5.7:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(null, '{"a":"avalues","b":"{\\"a\\":\\"avalues\\"}"}');
```

I queried the data and got this output:

```
select json_pretty(data) from test;
+----------------------------------------------------+
| json_pretty(data)                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| {
  "a": "avalues",
  "b": "{\"a\":\"avalues\"}"
} |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I don't know why you are storing a JSON string inside a JSON document. That's too error-prone to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful escaping single quotes. But you do not need the \" in the first query